# Hibernate session management for multiple transactions ?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the best way for maintaning Hibernate session for multiple database transactions? Do I need to open and close each session every time or should I rely upon `getCurrentSession()`? Whats the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best approach will be to obtain sessions via `openSession()` and release them via `disconnect()`. This will cause the database connection to be returned to the Hibernate connection pool, and thus, if you're not executing all trasactions at once, your sessions will be created from the existing connections (where possible) and overall performance will be sane.